# VBA code for "Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style" for footnotes in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am interested in the "Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style" being checked as default when adding a new footnote in a document.
So far I have this code:

```
Sub NoSpace()
    ActiveDocument.Styles("Footnote text") _
        .NoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle = True
End Sub
```

Which works okay, but only after adding a footnote and then running the code. I am interested it in working as a default, ie. when i open a document and add a footnote, I want the box to be checked. I hope someone can help me with this issue.

Comment: That should work when run before you add footnotes as well. The key is the formatting of the Footnote Text Style. See my page on styles http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Overview. I agree with Timothy Rylatt that no vba is needed though, just modify the style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want "Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style" set as a default then make sure that the template you use to create your documents has that set for the Footnote Text style. VBA code isn't required for this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both very much! I worked when i changed the setting in the template.

Comment: Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)